# Angular2 - Pushing data to an array from a subscribed observable

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component that is subscribed to a `Subject` and receives data upon a button click.

I am storing this data in an array and all is working fine. However, I am trying to only push new data to the array instead of any duplicates that already exist.

I accomplished this with `lodash` using the `_uniqBy` method.

My issue is that it is overwriting my `importResults` array each time I press the button instead of only pushing data to it that doesn't already exist.

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, OnInit, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MassEmpService } from '../shared';
import { ImportResults } from '../definitions';
import * as _ from "lodash";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-employee-selection',
    templateUrl: './employee-selection.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./employee-selection.component.css']
})

export class EmployeeSelectionComponent implements OnInit {

    // Define our search results
    importResults: ImportResults[];

    constructor(
        private _massEmpService: MassEmpService
    ) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        // Subscribe to our subject that lets us know about the added employees
        this._massEmpService.importedData.subscribe(obj => {
            if (obj) {
                // Ensure that we have unique results in our imported data
                this.importResults.push(_.uniqBy(obj, 'QID'));
            }
        });
    }

    // On clear employees
    clearEmployees() {
        this._massEmpService.updateImportData(null);
    }
}
```

When I tried using `push`, I get the error of `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`.

My end goal here is that I only want to push data to `importResults` if it doesn't already exist in there, instead of overwriting the whole thing.

**Update:**

Changing `importResults: ImportResults[];` to `importResults: ImportResults[] = [];` seems to have changed my data structure and now the `*ngFor` is not displaying the data.

**Before the initialization:**

[image]

**After the initialization:**

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<tr *ngFor="let i of importResults">

</tr>
```

Comment: line 15: `importResults: ImportResults[] = [];`

Comment: @HaveSpacesuit Updated question with the results of that change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have only declared the variable and not initialized which is why it is throwing error.

Just update -

```
 importResults: ImportResults[] =[] ;
```

This would fix your problem.

**update**
As you said pushing data alters the structure you must do for each on  the results then. 
E. G

```
_.uniqBy(obj, 'QID'). ForEach(p => this.importResults.push(p)); }
```

Comment: Tried this and added my results to the original question.

Comment: Then wrap it under a for each.

Comment: `core.es5.js:1020 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_lodash__.uniqBy(...).foreach is not a function`